# MSVS 2013 toolchain with other IDE's

Tags: windows, netbeans, sdk, codeblocks, cross-compiling

Can Netbeans 8, or Code::blocks be configured to use the compiler, linker, and debugger that comes with MSVS 2013 Express (or the equivalent Windows SDK package). I found where everything is installed and I have tried to set this up in Code::Blocks, but it doesn't seem to want to find any of these tools. Thanks very much.

Answer (score 0):

Prior to launching the IDE of your choice, set the environment and PATH such that the tools are available.  Run this command:

```
c:\<your visual studio install path>\vc\bin\vcvars32.bat
```

On my install, I have Visual Studio installed in `c:\vstudio`, so I type `c:\vstudio\vc\bin\vcvars32.bat`

This will add the compiler (cl.exe) to the PATH as well as define INCLUDES and LIB environment variables (and some Windows SDK environment variables)

Then in the IDE configuration, you should be specify cl.exe as the compiler and make use of the other visual studio tools from the IDE's project configuration.

Comment: @Mike - Most likely not.

Comment: I'm still toying around with code::blocks on this issue, but it seams that Netbeans is as friendly to MS as VS is to GNU. I expect this from MS but the Open Source community.